# Java: Error in class

Tags: java, android

How do I solve this error?

```
'{' expected public class pa5 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class pa1 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pa1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of the way you named your class. The name you give to your class has to follow a number of standard rules. I'll just run through the rules that are causing you to have this error. To learn fully about these conventions, check [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions) out.

- It cannot contain a space character (it must be one word).
- The class name must be the same as the name of the file it is stored in. Therefore, if your class is called **MainActivity**, it must be saved in a file called **MainActivity.java**.

For your code to run, change the name of your class from `pa1 MainActivity` to `pa1`. At the end, your code should look this way:

```
public class pa1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pa1);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**You are getting this error because of the define your class Way**

```
public class pa1 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pa1);
}
}
```

This is the wrong way to define **public class pa1 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity** please change this line :

```
public class Pa1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.pa1);
}
```

it helps you try this

Answer (score 0):

If `pa1` is an activity then `MainActivity` should be removed. And the class name you saved as `pa1`. So remove `MainActivity` from define class. The class would be like this.

```
public class pa1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pa1);
    }
}
```